# Is there any way I can play multiplayer Terraria on a single display on the Steam Deck?

Tags: terraria, mods, steam-deck

I either want to play split screen on a TV or use a mod that keeps all players in view of the camera kind of like in Super Smash Bros.

I found Nucleus co-op for Windows but dual booting on my main PC always causes Windows to corrupt its own partition. And I doubt it will work in Wine because of what the devs said on Github.